# How to return the component with the data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I´m trying to do a list of divs that need to have content of my firebase cloud storage. But I don't know how I can execute my code that get the data from the firebase and return MyNotes with the data.

See this:

```
class HandleMyNotes extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const db = firebase.firestore();

    db.collection("posts")
      .where("author.email", "==", this.props.authorEmail)
      .get()
      .then(querySnapshot => {
        querySnapshot.map(doc => {
          return <MyNotes data={doc.data()} key={doc.id} />;
        });
      })
      .catch(() => {
        alert("An error was happend");
      });
  }

  render() {
    return <MyNotes />;
  }
}
```

This works but not return the data, and If i trying to put the data into render(){} it's not work because maybe I'm not returning MyNotes

What can I do?

That's the data what I receive when i console.log(querySnapshot)

```
QuerySnapshot
docs: (...)
empty: (...)
metadata: SnapshotMetadata {hasPendingWrites: false, fromCache: false}
query: (...)
size: (...)
_cachedChanges: null
_cachedChangesIncludeMetadataChanges: null
_firestore: Firestore {_queue: AsyncQueue, INTERNAL: {…}, _config: FirestoreConfig, _databaseId: DatabaseId, _dataConverter: UserDataConverter, …}
_originalQuery: Query {path: ResourcePath, explicitOrderBy: Array(0), filters: Array(1), limit: null, startAt: null, …}
_snapshot: ViewSnapshot {query: Query, docs: DocumentSet, oldDocs: DocumentSet, docChanges: Array(1), mutatedKeys: SortedSet, …}
__proto__: Object
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not return components from lifecycle methods.
Set the api data fetched in local state and then pass that to the component in the render function.

```
componentDidMount() {
  const db = firebase.firestore();

  db.collection("posts")
    ...
    .then(querySnapshot => {
      this.setState({ data: querySnapshot })
    })
    ...
  }

  render() {
    return <MyNotes data={this.state.data} />;
  }
```

Comment: Hmm okay, I' try

Comment: you will need to loop over the data inside MYNotes to create/display individual notes OR you can loop over it int he above render function

Comment: But, I have many posts in my storage and I' trying to map every

Comment: Is MyNotes a component to display all notes or a single note?

Comment: Is a component to display all notes

<div id="notes" className="p-grid">
        <NoteComponent />
      </div>

Comment: So thats inside MyNotes...so you can loop over data to create each note

Comment: Hmm but I'm handling the data in a Container and then passing the data to the component

Comment: Thats fine..will setup a sandbox in a few and let you know

Answer (score 0):

```
class HandleMyNotes extends Component {
  state = {
    isLoading: false,
    err: null,
    posts: [],
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    const db = firebase.firestore();

    this.setState({
     isLoading: true,
    });

    db.collection("posts")
      .where("author.email", "==", this.props.authorEmail)
      .get()
      .then(querySnapshot => {
        this.setState({
         isLoading: false,
         posts: querySnapshot.map(note => note.data()),
        });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        this.setState({
         isLoading: false,
         err,
        });
      });
  }

  render() {
    const {
      isLoading,
      err,
      notes,
    } = this.state;
    // if loading or error you can handle here.
    return (
      <div>
        {notes.map(note => <Note key={note.id} data={note}/>)}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Bro, Why using .then(querySnapshot => {
        querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
          this.setState({ isLoading: false, notes: doc.data() });
        });
      })

Comment: I only get one of the notes, but no every note?

Comment: No you will get every note. My assumption was that querySnapshot was an array of posts, is that wrong? If it is an array it will set this.state.posts to the posts you just retrieved. You will need MyNotes, to extract those posts one by one, I would suggest a component called Note

Comment: They represent the state for your component. it's either loading data from firebase or it is not, it has a list of notes, and it has the potential to have an error(From the firebase call). Prior, to loading data from firebase we set isLoading to true. After the data is loading successfully we set isLoading to false/update posts. If the data is loaded unsuccessfully we set err to the error returned from firebase, and isLoading to false.

Comment: Yes, I have a component for every note, but that's problem, if i console.log(querySnapshot) I have many many info and thats like wtf where's the notes

Comment: And when I use forEach if i console.log I receive three objects (that's the notes count) querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
          this.setState({ isLoading: false, notes: doc.data() });
        });

Comment: Please see updated posts you can use map to get return an array of note.data()

Comment: I get this An error was happend :TypeError: querySnapshot.map is not a function

Comment: querySnapshot.map(note => {
          this.setState({ isLoading: false, notes: note.data() });
        });

That not work

Comment: That means querySnapshot is not an array, can you output the value of querySnapshot, and update the original post.

Comment: You are updating the state for every 'note'. You want a list of note.data(). Look at where i'm using map in the example.